# Sql Self join query? How to get categories sub categories?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I've a database table, which has the following form

```
catID | category      | parentID
1     | firstCategory | null
2     | SubCategory1  | 1
3     | SubCategory2  | 1
4     | subSub1       | 3
```

and so on...

There are multiple level of categories. What query can be used to get the records in the following format:

```
catID | category 
1     | firstCategory
2     | firstCategory/SubCategory1
3     | firstCategory/SubCategory2
4     | firstCategory/SubCategory2/subSub1
```

The category id will be the id of the last category. How to write a query to join the categories to all levels? The exact number of levels for different categories is different?

I'm using mySQL.

Comment: Do you know the max depth of the nesting? If not, this becomes an iterative function and needs more complicated code.

Comment: I'm a MSSQL user and in this DB engine we have a XMLPath() function which do exactly what you want. Maybe an advance MySql user could tell you if a similar function exist in MySQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a maximum depth of 6 (including root), you can use this

```
select l0.catID,
    concat(
      case when l5.catID is null then '' else concat(l5.category, '/') end
    , case when l4.catID is null then '' else concat(l4.category, '/') end
    , case when l3.catID is null then '' else concat(l3.category, '/') end
    , case when l2.catID is null then '' else concat(l2.category, '/') end
    , case when l1.catID is null then '' else concat(l1.category, '/') end
    , l0.category)
from catcat l0
left join catcat l1 on l0.parentID=l1.catID
left join catcat l2 on l1.parentID=l2.catID
left join catcat l3 on l2.parentID=l3.catID
left join catcat l4 on l3.parentID=l4.catID
left join catcat l5 on l4.parentID=l5.catID
```

Expand the pattern as required for longer max depths.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has this functionality, and the company I work for uses it for exactly what you are describing.  The queries can be quite heavy at times though.  A good writeup of the functions ("start with" and "connect by" keywords) is found here at this link, along with pseudo code you might try to wrap your head around...though cyberkiwi's answer is probably just fine for all practical purposes...

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to what cyberkiwi said: Query the whole table and to the tree building in memory. Imperative languages are well suited for that while SQL is not. The performance will be much better (because SQL has to scan the table not only once but for every level).