# Mysql Joining multiple IDs used in other field within the same table (Self Join)

Tags: mysql, self-join

I did try to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995721/sql-self-join-query-how-to-get-categories-sub-categories)

But in my case, Im using the pk id to be used by the other field of the same table

**Sample Tables:**

**1. Customer**

Fields:

> Customer_ID, Name, Category_ID,  **Realty_Firm**

**2.Category**

Fields:

> Category_ID, Description

Sample Data for Category:

```
Category_ID | Description
1           | Agent
2           | Broker
```

---

Sample Data for Customer:

```
Customer_ID  | Name    | Category_ID | Realty Firm
1            | AgentName1  | 1           | 6
2            | AgentName2  | 1           | 6
3            | AgentName3  | 1           | 6
4            | AgentName4  | 1           | 6
5            | AgentName5  | 1           | 7
6            | BrokerName1 | 2           | null
7            | BrokerName2 | 2           | null
```

---

**Note 1:** *Realty_Firm field data comes from Broker Customer ID (6 and 7 are the IDs of Category Broker)*

**Note 2 :** Realty_Firm field is only required if the Category selected is Agent(1)

**Question:** How will I make a query that will group Customer by Category?
Seems like an easy work but the problem is How Can I join the Realty_Firm field to the Customer_ID of the same table?

```
Select Cat.Description, Custom.Name as Broker, Cust.Name as Agent From Customer as Cust 
Inner Join Category as Cat ON Cust.Category_ID=Cat.Category_ID 
INNER JOIN  Customer as Custom ON Custom.Customer_ID=Cust.Realty_Firm
```

The above query has double Join to the Customer table with different aliases but returns only the rows with Realty_Field value (Broker) **and NOT the entire records of Agents belongs to Brokers.**

**Sample Query output** *(showing the redable record and not the ID for easy reference and for the sake of sample):*

```
Description | Broker       | Agent
Broker      | BrokerName1  | AgentName1
Broker      | BrokerName1  | AgentName2
Broker      | BrokerName1  | AgentName3
Broker      | BrokerName1  | AgentName4
Broker      | BrokerName1  | AgentName5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
Select Cat.Description, Custom.Name as Broker, Cust.Name as Agent From Customer as Cust 
Inner Join Category as Cat ON Cust.Category_ID=Cat.Category_ID 
LEFT JOIN  Customer as Custom ON Custom.Customer_ID=Cust.Realty_Firm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name, b.name, c.description from customer a
left join customer b on a.realty_firm = b.customer_id
left join category c on b.category_id = c.category_iD
 where a.category_id = 1;
```

Outputs

```
AgentName1 |    BrokerName1 | Broker
AgentName2 |    BrokerName1 | Broker
AgentName3 |    BrokerName1 | Broker
AgentName4 |    BrokerName1 | Broker
AgentName5 |    BrokerName2 | Broker
```